# Using ArcPy to determine ArcMap document version

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, mxd

Is there a way with ArcPy to identify the version of a [Map Document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000n000000) (MXD).  I am working on a solution to [inventory our MXD's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61724/search-mxds-for-feature-class) and would like to know if a document is 8.1, 9.2, 10.0, etc.

I am currently using ArcMap 10.0, but if there is an update in 10.1 that does not exist in 10.0, I am interested in that, too.

I see there is a previous question of [How can you find ArcGIS version programatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48260/how-can-you-find-arcgis-version-programatically), but it references all ArcObjects solutions (which I suppose I could [call from python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python), but I would prefer not to).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I developed this kludge to parse version numbers from MXD documents. It basically reads the first 4000 or so characters of an MXD document and searches for a version number. I tested with MXD versions 9.2, 9.3, 10.0, and 10.1.

```
import re

def getMXDVersion(mxdFile):
    matchPattern = re.compile("9.2|9.3|10.0|10.1|10.2")
    with open(mxdFile, 'rb') as mxd:
        fileContents = mxd.read().decode('latin1')[1000:4500]
        removedChars = [x for x in fileContents if x not in [u'\xff',u'\x00',u'\x01',u'\t']]
        joinedChars = ''.join(removedChars)
        regexMatch = re.findall(matchPattern, joinedChars)
        if len(regexMatch) > 0:
            version = regexMatch[0]
            return version
        else:
            return 'version could not be determined for ' + mxdFile
```

Here is an example of scanning a folder for mxd files and printing the version and names

```
import os
import glob
folder = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mxd_examples'
mxdFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.mxd'))
for mxdFile in mxdFiles:
    fileName = os.path.basename(mxdFile)
    version = getMXDVersion(mxdFile)
    print version, fileName
```

Which returns this:

```
>>> 
10.0 Arch_Cape_DRG.mxd
9.2 class_exercise.mxd
9.3 colored_relief2.mxd
10.1 CountyIcons.mxd
10.0 DEM_Template.mxd
9.2 ex_2.mxd
10.0 nairobimap.mxd
10.0 slope_script_example.mxd
10.1 TrailMapTemplateBetter.mxd
10.0 Wickiup_Mountain_DEM.mxd
>>>
```

Answer (score 16):

The function below is based on Ryan's idea, but is a little more direct. ArcGIS map documents are actually OLE documents, which can be parsed with the `oletools` module (available on pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oletools). The function opens the file and reads the version string. Tested with 9.0, 9.3, 10.1 and 10.3, but should work with anything (not sure about 3.x...).

```
from oletools.thirdparty import olefile

def mxd_version(filename):
    ofile = olefile.OleFileIO(filename)
    stream = ofile.openstream('Version')
    data = stream.read().decode('utf-16')
    version = data.split('\x00')[1]
    return version

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(mxd_version(sys.argv[-1]))
```