# Opening .mxd files in Python not via ArcPy?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, mxd

I am an old user of Python, but relatively new to GIS. I have a `.mxd` file and would like to read it into Python.

Is `arcpy` the only way to do so?

I tried with `pyshp` but it does not accept this file extension.

Is there perhaps another package for `python3` for working with data in this format?

Comment: It's a proprietary binary format. You could read the bytestream, but you'd have to reverse-engineer it to have meaning, and the format mutates with each release. Finally, it doesn't contain much data, just metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mxd files are map documents containing information:

- references to the data sources;
- map layer symbology;
- map document metadata;
- optionally layout configuration;
- some GUI layout information.

Since it is a binary file, you would need to use a piece of software that is capable of reading it. If you would like to get access to the file programmatically specifically using Python you have really three options:

1. Use `arcpy` site-package that comes with ArcGIS.
2. Use Python `comtypes` package that can provide an interface to ArcObjects (the COM objects ArcGIS is built upon). Read more on how you can access ArcObjects using Python in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python). There is a post on reading version of mxd file using `comtypes` [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150491/checking-mxd-version-using-arcpy).
3. Read binary data and try to parse. There is code that tries this [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150491/checking-mxd-version-using-arcpy).